# Making two adjacent div's rollover together if you hover over either div

Tags: css, image, text, hover, rollover

I have created a DIV with two DIV's inside it; A DIV with a rollover image and A DIV below it with text and normal rollover behaviors.

They text describes the image and they are both links to the same place so I want them to both rollover together when the mouse is hovering over either one.

Can anyone tell me how I could do that with just CSS?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could put the `:hover` on the outer `<div>` and then use that to effect the rollovers on the inner `<div>`s. For example:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner-img">
    </div>
    <div class="inner-text">
        Where is pancakes house?
    </div>
</div>
```

And some CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.inner-img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/200/100);
}
.inner-text {
    width: 200px;
}
.outer:hover .inner-img {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/201/100);
}
.outer:hover .inner-text {
    background-color: #dfd;
}
```

And an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/3bXhA/

Comment: Thank's mu!  Your answer put me on the right track and I really appreciate the help!!!